# I want to view a specific category on my modal.tpl file PRESTASHOP

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

So I want after adding a product to the cart I want the user to be able to choose additions from the **modal.tpl** file which was the add to the cart confirmation, I only know that I need to edit the PHP controller for **modal.tpl** and add the following:

```
protected function getAccessoriesProducts()
{
    $accessories_cat_id = 239;
    $acc_category = new Category($accessories_cat_id);
    $acc_products = $acc_category->getProducts($this->context->language->id, (int)$this->p, (int)$this->n, $this->orderBy, $this->orderWay);

    return $acc_products;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what controller to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally figued it out, so the file I needed to modifer was **/modules/ps_shoppingcart/controllers/front/ajax.php** and what I did was adding this line of code and access the `$add_products` array from the *modal.tpl* template

```
$id_category = 10
$add_products = $add_products = Product::getProducts(Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, 0, 'date_upd', 'ASC', $id_category, true);
```